# How can I curve a design I made to make it perfectly match the curve of a circle?

Tags: vector, logo

I would like to make a logo that has two simplified branches of barley that mirror each other and curve to a perfectly circular shape, like the following from http://culination.co:

[image: olive branch logo]

I have tried to do it in Illustrator, Sketch and Pixelmator, but I can't seem to figure it out and can't find a tutorial. I tried making the pattern straight and curving it and when that didn't work, I tried making it curved, which was a total mess.

Does anyone have an idea how to do this elegantly?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

### Using Illustrator

To create those branches of barley like that, you could draw them straight then create an **Art Brush** out of them:

[image: Straight Barley]

#### Create a new Art Brush

Select your art, then **Brushes** panel click the ***New Brush*** button in the bottom right

[image: Create a new art brush]

#### Apply the art brush to a curve

[image: Apply the art brush]

The brush will nicely flow with whatever curves you apply it to

[image: goofy stuff]